# double value calculation

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double txt1 = 55.00;
    double txt2 = 3.00;
    result = 0.00;
    txt1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    txt2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);          
    result = txt1/txt3;
    textBox3.Text = result.ToString(0.00);
}
```

Answer should be `18.33`.

Now my question is I want to calculate with some other number. Like e.g.: my other no is `5`
I want to multiply `18 * 5`, not `18.33 * 5`.
I want to multiply by before `decimal` value with any number.

Could anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried int.Parse()?

Comment: `.ToString(0)`? if you don't want the decimal places, why are you asking for them in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: Well, which variable holds this `18` value and what is that variable's type?  Hint: If you want to use an integer, use an integer.

Comment: i can use .ToString(0) but backend its multipled with 18.33 not 18

Comment: yes,also tried double.Parse(),my manditary my values should be in double not int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you want to take 18.33 and just use the *integer* part of the number and multiply that by something else....like the number 5.

Here's 2 ways you can do it:

```
var something = (int)result * 5;                 //equals 90 (int)
var somethingElse = Math.Truncate(result) * 5;   //equals 90.0 (double)
```